# How do I use variable input in a catch?

Tags: c#

I want to use a ReadLine() method input in a catch statement but I get "Use of unassigned local variable" error. How can I fix this?

```
    char entry;
    try
    {   
        Write("Please type a char variable value >> ");
        entry = Convert.ToChar(ReadLine());
    }
    //how do I make the incorrect input entered for the entry variable display in the catch
    catch
    {  
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is not an acceptable char variable value" , entry);
    }
```

Comment: [Char.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.tryparse) -- [Console.ReadKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey)

Comment: Since the line is thrown before assigning the variable, it is by definition unassigned, so you can't use it.

Comment: Imagine what would happen if the `Write` method failed before `entry` could be assigned. What would the catch handler do?

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly the problem. You are trying to use a variable that is not guaranteed to be assigned. Indeed, the only way to get into the `catch` is in fact when the variable is _not_ assigned. You need to take a little more time to think through the logical sequence of steps in your code and especially rethink what data it is you actually want to show the user when the conversion to a `char` value fails.

Answer (score -1):

If `Convert.ToChar` throws an exception, then the return value of the function is "undefined", because the input string is not a valid `char`, so you can't store it in your `char` variable.

```csharp
Console.Write("Please type a char variable value >> ");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
try
{
    char entry = Convert.ToChar(input);
}
catch
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is not an acceptable char variable value", input);
}
```